# Facebook Ads API time_range Issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to use the Facebook Graph API to get the list of ads for specific dates. The issue is that the time_range value I am passing is being accepted by the Facebook API endpoint but the result is incorrect.

Here is a sample endpoint I am using:

[https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/act_xxxxxxxx/ads?fields=id,ad_review_feedback,updated_time,preview_shareable_link&limit=5&access_token=xxxxxxxx&time_range={since:'2022-03-01',until:'2022-03-02'}](https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/act_xxxxxxxx/ads?fields=id,ad_review_feedback,updated_time,preview_shareable_link&limit=5&access_token=xxxxxxxx&time_range=%7Bsince:%272022-03-01%27,until:%272022-03-02%27%7D)

The result list shows a list of ads beyond the indicated time ranges.

Comment: Same problem as this, perhaps? https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/592418868011048/

Comment: Hi CBroe I already tried the solution on the link before posting this question but it does not work on the /ads endpoint.